# Variable returning string as opposed to defined parameter

Tags: python-3.x

I'm fairly new to coding and was just wondering how I would make this variable take the pre-defined parameters for it and not just take the string entered.

```
ARS = arsenal = ([1500] , [350])
x = input('Home Team: ')
print(ARS)
print(x)

>> ([1500], [350])
>> Home Team: ARS
>> ARS
```

Whereas I'd like the x variable to give me the two lists if possible. 
Thanks for any help.

Comment: What is your expected output? I don't totally get what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is called a dictionary.

Just a minor change to what you have.

```
dict = {'ARS' : ([1500],[350])}
x = input('Home Team: ')
print(x)
print(dict[x])
```

I believe what you were trying to do with having both `arsenal` and `ARS` set to that value was to allow for different types of user input that will still lead to a result. Unfortunately, Python doesn't natively support multi key dictionaries. So instead, you could have a secondary dictionary with aliases and do something like the following.

```
dict = {'ARS' : ([1500],[350])}
alias_dict = {'arsenal' : 'ARS'}

x = input('Home Team: ')

print(x)

if x in dict:
    print(dict[x])
elif (x in alias_dict) and (alias_dict[x] in dict):
    print(dict[alias_dict[x])
else:
    print("Invalid input. No matching team.")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a dictionary to hold the team names and related numbers like so:

```
data = {"ARS":[1500,300]}
x = input("Home team: ")
print data[x]
```